# HOw to show a custom subclass of UIView in ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Xcode 5

I am trying to create a custom cropping rectangle to crop image. FOr that I understand I need to override drawRect() method in a class extending UIView. But then I don't know how to use that class in ViewController to show it.

Please correct if I am going in wrong direction. I am a little new to this.

**MDCustomCropRect.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MDCustomCropRect : UIView

@end
```

**MDCustomCropRect.m**

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);   //this is the transparent color
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, rectangle);    //this will draw the border
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add your view as a subview of your UIViewController's view.

In your viewController code, typically in `viewDidLoad` method :

```
  // create your view
  MDCustomCropRect *myView = [[MDCustomCropRect alloc] init];
  [self.view addSubView:myView]  
  // you can manually set your view frame - in this case use initWithFrame: instead of init 
  // OR use layout constraints : define and add constraints AFTER your inserted your view as a subview
```

**EDIT**:

In your case, as you're only drawing a rectangle - which is what `UIView` is - you could instead to the following :

```
   UIView *myRectangleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100)];
   myRectangleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   myRectangleView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
   myRectangleView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5].CGColor;
   [self.view addSubView:myRectangleView];
```

There is no need for a specific `drawRect` in your case

Comment: But I already have a UIImageView there which consists an image that I took through camera. I want to put the rectangle over it, not replace it.

Comment: and what's the problem? a view can have multiple subviews :)

Comment: The problem right now is the rectangle is not coming on the initial screen. So I thought it was because I already have a UIImageView in place.
BTW is the code that I have written in drawRect sufficient to show up a rect on adding it as a subview as you mentioned?

Comment: in your code, replace `rectangle` - which, with it origin.y = 100, seems expressed in superview's coordinates - by `self.bounds`, and it should work. More generally, a View should NOT have to know about its superview : controller or superview sets the views's frame. And view uses its `bounds` to know which size it is

Answer (score 1):

In your viewController

```
MDCustomCropRect *myView = [[MDCustomCropRect alloc] init];
myView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,200,100);
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.view addSubView:myView]
```

Comment: Hi! your code is working perfectly. But what is wrong with my code? Because i will need to add circles at corners, handle touch events and lots of things. So I prefer doing everything in separate class only.